# When a android nearby places get error

Tags: android, google-maps

When i click hospital nearby place get error..

```
Returning data= {"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 103.247.48.75, with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

05-10 16:22:38.297 4057-4057/pilojan.slbroute D/json data: {   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 103.247.48.75, with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

05-10 16:22:38.297 4057-4057/pilojan.slbroute D/nearbyplacesdata: called parse method
05-10 16:22:45.222 4057-4057/pilojan.slbroute D/MapsActivity: url = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=8.9908983,80.599&radius=10000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBFJUy7jJJaOECHEtVFs2WkTalBwtinQao
05-10 16:22:45.267 4057-4275/pilojan.slbroute
```

Comment: **This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.** Did you read the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the application is not authorized to use the Api key. To be able to use the API key follow the steps:

1. Go to [Developer Console] (https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started).
2. In the Credentials, under Create Credentials , select API key.
3. Click on key name, make sure Application restriction is "none". Then save the changes.
4. Now use this API key while making the request to nearby places.

Hope this answer will help you and other viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you enable place api service in google console in your project and also define key in url place api key ..

refer below link i pass in key place api key and i get data ..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyC4dszhtREoFFtRVGgt2obok0Ux25Y8w7Y

Comment: more information refer this link https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
     API Key: AIzaSyCZcrqHREVx5EZ5rpr9tuYX1yZdceTb7ZU

Comment: yes and also getting place api key refer this link https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

Comment: and also enable Google Places API then you get data.